# Yet another mod_rewrite query -- Cannot rewrite to pretty url and keep query strings

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm literally at the end of my tether with this. I've researched many other questions and answers on stackoverflow but still can't find the solution i need. I'm starting to think what i want to do is not possible.

So... the problem is this. I want to turn the following:
e.g.

```
www.mydomain.com/visa-information/country.php?country={COUNTRY-NAME}&passport={PASSPORT-NAME}
```

To the following pretty url:

```
www.mydomain.com/visa-information/{COUNTRY-NAME}-visa-for-{PASSPORT-NAME}-citizens/
```

I have a partially successful rule in my htacces file as so:

```
RewriteRule ^/visa-information/([A-Za-z-]+)-visa-for-([A-Za-z-]+)-citizens/?$ visa-information/country.php?country=$1&passport=$2  [NC]
```

which works fine and does what i want if i enter the url into the browser address bar, but the real problem i'm having is getting it to re-direct to the pretty url via a form i have on pretty much every page of the site.

I've tried various re-direct rules like the one below:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} country=([A-Za-z-]+)&passport=([A-Za-z-]+) [NC]
RewriteRule visa-information/country.php  visa-information/%1-visa-for-%2-citizens/? [R,NC,L]
```

But no luck. I've also tried adding the QSA flag to the above re-direct rule, but it just ends up with an endless loop.

I have tried using a location php re-direct header at the top of the country.php page to re-direct after form submission like so:

```
if(isset($_GET['country']) && isset($_GET['passport'])) {
header("Location: " . $dir . "/visa-information/" . $currentCountry . "-visa-for-" . $currentPassport . "-citizens/");
exit();
}
```

I was expecting the above to work like entering the pretty url directly into the browser works, but it doesn't, just gives me a 404 error.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Jordash

**EDIT**

My local directory structure is as follows:

```
/webserver/mydomain.com/visa-information/etc...
```

On the live server it will be:

```
mydomain.com/visa-information/etc..
```

As i am using an Apache Alias on my local machine i have set RewriteBase as:

```
RewriteBase /webserver/mydomain.com/
```

I currently have the following set of RewriteRules adapted from what anubhava gave me:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} visa-information/country.php     [NC]    
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} country=([A-Za-z-]+)&passport=([A-Za-z-]+)  [NC]
RewriteRule visa-information/       visa-information/%1-visa-for-%2-citizens/? [R=301,L,QSA]

# internal redirect from pretty URL to old URL
RewriteRule ^visa-information/([A-Za-z-]+)-visa-for-([A-Za-z-]+)-citizens/?$    visa-information/country.php?country=$1&passport=$2 [NC,L]
```

This currently gives me an endless re-direct loop, both when entering the pretty url in the browser bar, and when using my form, however if i disable the top 3 rules then i find i can enter the pretty url into the address bar and the rewrite works, but not from the form submission of course.

I really don't know what i'm doing wrong. Why is there an endless loop?

Comment: You can't change the form? Sounds easier.

Comment: How should i change the form?

Comment: With a search and replace? Maybe use regex?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how first rule is working for you since `RewriteRule` doesn't match leading slash in `.htaccess`. Also to redirect old url to pretty URL you need to use `THE_REQUEST` variable that represents original request received by Apache from your browser. Replace your code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# external redirect from old URL to pretty URL
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+visa-information/country\.php\?country=([^\s&]+)&passport=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /visa-information/%1-visa-for-%2-citizens/? [R=301,L]

# internal redirect from pretty URL to old URL
RewriteRule ^visa-information/([a-z-]+)-visa-for-([a-z-]+)-citizens/?$ /visa-information/country.php?country=$1&passport=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: I have tried your above code but it does not work unfortunately. After the form submission it just displays the country.php with query string as normal. When I enter the pretty url directly into browser address bar I get a 404.

Comment: RewriteBase does matter here. Going to bed now but if you post your complete latest code I can provide you edited answer in the morning.

Comment: I am testing locally and have an alias set up for Apache, RewriteBase is set as --- /webserver/mydomain.com/ --- The htaccess file is located in the mydomain.com file, where index.php is etc. I have various other rewrite rules in place on the htaccess and all work correctly, it's just this query string situation i am having an issue with (Note i have disabled all other rewrite rules when testing for this one i ma having issues with).

Comment: When you enter `www.mydomain.com/visa-information/country.php?country={COUNTRY-NAME}&passport={PASSPORT-NAME}` does it show correct content?

Comment: well i have to enter `http://localhost/webserver/visaknowhow.com/visa-information/etc..` for testing locally, but for the live site it works as you have stated.

Comment: What is this `/webserver/` after `http://localhost` You never mentioned it before. If this part is there then let me know.

Comment: I mentioned before that i'm usinag an Alias with Apache and the alias root document is `webserver/mydomain.com/etc`. I have RewriteBase set as `/webserver/mydomain.com/`. I had the rewrite/redirect semi-working at one point as it was displaying the correct the page with the pretty url, however the query string values were not carried through so therefore the information on the page was not displayed correctly. That was last week and i have tinkered with the code so much, i can't even get it back to that stage now.

Comment: So `/visa-information/country.php` is actually `/webserver/mydomain.com//visa-information/country.php` on file system?

Comment: no sorry it is - `/webserver/mydomain.com/visa-information/etc`

Comment: Sorry it is very confusing for me. You need to clearly write some info about present directory structure in your question.

Comment: I've edited my original query to show clearer directory structure

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue was actually with my php form and not the mod_Rewrite rules. The form "action" was pointing to the same form page (as in    $SERVER['PHP_SELF']) which works fine without the rewrite rules, but causes an endless loop when they are activated.

I simply made a search_action.php page and then redirect the form there using a php header to the pretty url:

```
header("Location: " . $dir . "/visa-information/" . $currentCountry . "-visa-for-" . $currentPassport . "-citizens/");
exit();
```

The mod_rewrite rule I had originally works fine and now the user can get to the desired page with the pretty url from the form or by tyoing directly into the browser address bar.

I'm not sure it's actually possible to action a form to the same page whilst rewriting the query string, without using an intermediary action page from the form, or Javascript. I'm sure many of the more experienced programmers will have known this already, but not me unfortunately.